# Python: Use lambda functions with Row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a row in Python:

```
from trp import Document
def get_table_dic(json_data):
    doc = Document(json_data)
    for page in doc.pages:
        for table in page.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                print(row)
                for cell in row.cells:
                    print(cell.text)
```

Output or `print(row):`

```
[Dog ][Fish ][Monkey ][Cow ]
```

Output of `cell.text`:

```
Dog
Fish
Monkey
Cow
```

The row seems not the same as a list. I want to convert the row to a list:
This works:

```
def convert_row_to_list(row):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.cells:
        list_of_cells.append(cell.text)
    return list_of_cells
```

But I want to write this shorter (I'm using Python3):

```
def convert_row_to_list(row):
    list_of_cells = []
    # to test
    print(list(map(lambda x: list_of_cells.append(x), row.cells)))
```

But this gives:

```
[None, None, None, None]
```

How can I do solve this issue?

Comment: `append` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Try printing `list_of_cells` instead of the return value of `map`.

Comment: Never use a construct like `map` for side-effects, i.e. `lambda x: list_of_cells.append(x)`, don't do this.

Comment: Just use this ``(list(map(lambda x:x, row.cells)))``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return anything. You can use `map()` to call it, but you shouldn't use the return value. It updated `list_of_cells`, you should print that.

```
def convert_row_to_list(row):
    list_of_cells = []
    # to test
    map(lambda x: list_of_cells.append(x.text), row.cells)
    print(list_of_cells)
    return list_of_cells
```

But a list comprehension is simpler:

```
def convert_row_to_list(row):
    list_of_cells = [cell.text for cell in row]
    print(list_of_cells)
    return list_of_cells
```

Comment: @mealesbia please don't use `map` for side effects like what `append` does

Answer (score 1):

Using `append` in a `map` like that doesn't do what you want it to do, because append never returns anything. Map bases its output based on the return of the lambda/function its given.

It may be simplest to just use a list comprehension to do this:

```
from trp import Document 
def get_table_dic(json_data): 
    doc = Document(json_data) 
    for page in doc.pages: 
        for table in page.tables: 
            for row in table.rows:  
                rowaslist = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
```